# MySQL SELECT an md5

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to make a login form and in the DB I am saving the passwords as MD5 $password = md5($_POST['password']); but when I am trying to use the password SELECT * FROM `*******` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' but this is not working. The only thing I can think of is it being that I'm saving it as md5 and select plan text.

Comment: Do not use MD5 for password hashing. It is massively insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
"SELECT * FROM ******* WHERE username='$username' AND password='".md5($password)."'"
```

However, from your code is not visible, if you do some proper escaping on the variables, therefore the code seems vulnerable to SQL-Injections. You should properly escape variables before throwing them into a query.

Without going into too much detail, somebody could enter a username, so that the query ends up like

```
SELECT * FROM ******* WHERE username='admin' -- $username' AND password='".md5($password)."'"
```

which is perfectly valid, and will allow him to login with that user without knowing the password.

Comment: I'm new to this how would I go about doing that as I don't really know where to start and this is the way I have seen other people doing it.

Comment: @RyanJ Google for "SQL-Injection" and you will find a lot of examples how they work and how you can avoid them.

Comment: I have tried password='".md5($password)." but it's not working now erroring the page. Think it's got something to do with quotation marks, any idea ?